# Qt Qml Error: Unable to assign [undefined] to QString in a subclassed QAbstractItemModel for Qml TreeView

Tags: c++, qt, treeview, qml, qt-creator

I try to create a custom module for the Qml TreeView and I used Simpel Treeview Example as foundation, but I always get *"unabe to assign [undefined] to QString"*.

Here some infos u might need:

[Displayed view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtEEe.png)

Qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import cci.screenshotCreator.StructureDataModel 1.0

TreeView  {
    id: root
    state: "closed"
    TableViewColumn {
       role: "folderName"
       title: "Ordnerstruktur"
    }
    model: StructureDataModel{
        id: dataModel
    }

    itemDelegate: Item {
        height: 30
        Rectangle {
           id: rectangle
           color: styleData.selected ? "lightgray" : "#ffffff"
           border.width: styleData.selected ? 2 : 1
           border.color: styleData.selected ? "lightblue" : "#ababab"
           anchors.fill: parent
        }

    Text {
        id: folderText
        text: dataModel.folderName
        fontSizeMode: Text.Fit
        anchors.fill: parent
        font.pointSize: 12
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
    }
```

C++:

```
#include "structuredatamodel.h"

structureDataModel::structureDataModel(QObject *parent)
    : QAbstractItemModel(parent)
{
    QList<QVariant> rootData;
    rootData << "/";
    rootItem = new StructureItem(rootData);
    setupModelData(rootItem);
}

structureDataModel::~structureDataModel()
{
    delete rootItem;
}

QModelIndex structureDataModel::index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if(!hasIndex(row, column, parent))
        return QModelIndex();

    StructureItem *parentItem;

    if(!parent.isValid())
        parentItem = rootItem;
    else
        parentItem = static_cast<StructureItem*>(parent.internalPointer());

    StructureItem *childItem = parentItem->child(row);
    if(childItem)
        return createIndex(row, column, childItem);
    else
        return QModelIndex();
}

QHash<int, QByteArray> structureDataModel::roleNames() const
{
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    roles[structureRoles::folderName] = "folderName";
    return roles;
}

QModelIndex structureDataModel::parent(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if(!index.isValid())
        return QModelIndex();

    StructureItem *childItem = static_cast<StructureItem*>(index.internalPointer());
    StructureItem *parentItem = childItem->parentItem();

    if (parentItem == rootItem)
        return QModelIndex();

    return createIndex(parentItem->row(), 0, parentItem);
}

int structureDataModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    StructureItem *parentItem;
    if(parent.column() > 0)
        return 0;

    if(!parent.isValid())
        parentItem = rootItem;
    else
        parentItem = static_cast<StructureItem*>(parent.internalPointer());

    return parentItem->childCount();
}

int structureDataModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if(parent.isValid())
        return static_cast<StructureItem*>(parent.internalPointer())->columnCount();
    else
        return rootItem->columnCount();
}

QVariant structureDataModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if(!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();

    if(role != structureRoles::folderName)
        return QVariant();

    StructureItem *item = static_cast<StructureItem*>(index.internalPointer());


    return item->data(index.column()).toString();
}


Qt::ItemFlags structureDataModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if(!index.isValid())
        return 0;

    return QAbstractItemModel::flags(index);
}

QVariant structureDataModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const
{
    if (orientation == Qt::Horizontal && role == structureRoles::folderName)
        return rootItem->data(section);

    return QVariant();
}


void structureDataModel::setupModelData(StructureItem *parent)
{
    QList<QVariant> data;
    data << "Test";
    StructureItem *child = new StructureItem(data, parent);
    parent->appendChild(child);
}
```

The StructureItem is is the same as TreeItem (just a different name :) )
I made my own setupModelData so that model only have one row as root point.
Later I would like to have a editable treeview but for now a working read-only treeView should work right now.
I suspect that it has something to with the setupModelData or making the c++ visible for qml.

PS: I added qmlRegisterType("cci.screenshotCreator.StructureDataModel", 1, 0, "StructureDataModel"); to the main file to register the cpp class.

Minimal Application for testing:
https://pastebin.com/u/Klidrack (all files of my pastebin profile) :)

Comment: On which line do you get "unabe to assign [undefined] to QString"? 
on "text: dataModel.folderName"?

Comment: Oh sorry forgot that. yes dataModel.folderName

Comment: Just try to debug data function and what it returns.
QVariant structureDataModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    return QStringLiteral("test");
}

Comment: The data function returns test as it should in both cases(ur version and the original one) but still the same error msg and no text in my treeView.
But I also got some msg in the debug console:
QMetaProperty::read: Unable to handle unregistered datatype 'const QQuickPointerDevice*' for property 'QQuickPointerEvent::device' kernel\qmetaobject.cpp: 3016 and QVariant::save: unable to save type 'QModelIndex' (type id: 42).
 kernel\qvariant.cpp: 2150 
after I tried to look at the properties of structureView during debug mode.

Comment: Can you post your Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. So we can compile and reproduce the problem? To pastebin or somewhere. PS: or directly in your question

Comment: Added a link in my question.

Comment: _"Klidrack has no public pastes."_

Comment: nobody can see your pastebin except you. make it public

Comment: It's public now. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, didn't saw it at first look. 
There is diference between `ListView`'s and `TreeView`'s delegated components in `QML`.
In `TreeView` you have `itemDelegate` and all data are expanded through `styleData` properties.

in your case this should look like this:

```
itemDelegate: Item
    {
        height: 30
        Rectangle
        {
            id: rectangle
            color: styleData.selected ? "lightgray" : "#ffffff"
            border.width: styleData.selected ? 2 : 1
            border.color: styleData.selected ? "lightblue" : "#ababab"
            anchors.fill: parent
        }

        Text
        {
            id: folderText
            text: styleData.value
            fontSizeMode: Text.Fit
            anchors.fill: parent
            font.pointSize: 12
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
        }
    }
```